# Why does <textarea> in React accept a value attribute but in HTML, it does not?

Tags: html, reactjs, textarea

Not sure if this is React specific, but, why does the following work in React and render some text to the element:

```
<textarea value="Some text."></textarea>
```

but the same in plain HTML does not:

```
<textarea value="Some text."></textarea>
```

maybe I am missing something or done something foolish? Apologies and thanks in advance!

Comment: Because this is how the React team have build it. No other reason than them trying to make the API consistent between all form inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML the `text` area is a non-self-closing tag and has content. It defines its text by children.

[textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

```
<textarea id="story" name="story" rows="5" cols="33">
  It was a dark and stormy night...
</textarea>
```

In React it uses the `value` attribute. Note that is also self-closing and takes no children.

[textarea tag](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-textarea-tag)

This keeps the `textarea` element consistent with other form elements such as `input` and `select`.

```
<textarea
  id="story"
  name="story"
  rows="5"
  cols="33"
  value="It was a dark and stormy night..."
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `textarea` *child content* represents the *default* value of a text area, but the *`value` property* represents the *current* value.

It is the *current* value that needs to be manipulated via JS, not the default value.